# No warning for narrowing when initializing with parentheses

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

I stumbled upon a perplexing situation where I have found an obvious narrowing conversion, but I'm disappointed that the compiler (gcc-4.7.2) did not raise a warning despite `-Wall -Wnarrowing -pedantic` flags.  Please see the following program:

```c
struct A {
  int m;
  A( int m ) : m(m) {};
};

int main() {
  unsigned long v = 0;
  A a1(v);  // narrowing, but no warning (should this not cause a warning?)
  A a2{v};  // narrowing, warning raised (expected)
}
```

Initialization of `a1` seems to fly without so much as a peep from the compiler.  Just to make sure I wasn't going insane, I tried to initialize `a1` in the same manner, but with braces instead of parens.  The compiler warns about narrowing in the second case, as was expected.

To be clear:  I'm not asking about the legality of narrowing conversions in initialization-lists.  I know that's not legal--the curly-braced initialization of `a2` was a mere sanity-check.  **My question is unrelated to initialization lists.  This is not a duplicate question.**

Should the compiler not warn me about narrowing for the initialization of `a1`?

Comment: The constructor for `a1` can do one implicit conversion, while for `a2` cannot. Why do you think they should be the same?

Comment: What if you add the `-Wconversion` flag?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I am already aware that narrowing conversions within initialization lists are illegal.  I'm asking about the initializaiton with the parentheses.

Comment: @gx_ `-Wconversion` changes nothing.  I believe that is implied by `-Wall`

Comment: @IronSavior: Wconversion is not implied by Wall. And I'm getting warnings for this with Wall (and more with Wconversion) with GCC 4.7 and clang 3.3;

Comment: @Mat  When I comment out the line using the brace-initializer and compile using `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wconversion`, no warnings are raised at all.  I don't know what to say.

Comment: I don't know either, but even GCC 4.5.4 gives a warning with `-Wconversion`

Comment: which minor version of gcc-4.7 did you use?  Perhaps mine is out of date (4.7.2)

Comment: The correct flag for narrowing warnings is `-Wnarrowing` btw.

Comment: @Xeo as noted above, `-Wnarrowing` does not cause the warning to appear.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, that causes a warning to be raised--you're saying that it's because the compiler decided that there was no reason to complain because the conversion from `long` to `int` happens to not be a narrowing situation on my particular platform?  I guess the standard allows for the compiler to decide if it's ok in the context of platform for parens, where using the braces means there can't be any narrowing regardless of platform context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wsign-conversion` will generate a warning for that line of code - `-Wconversion` will not when `unsigned long` and `int` have the same size (which is true on many platforms, even some 64-bit platforms). For C code, `-Wconversion` will enable `-Wsign-conversion` implicitly, but that doesn't happen with C++ for some reason.

If you change the type of `v` to `long long`, `-Wconversion` by itself will generate a warning (assuming that `int` is 32-bits).

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight.  I'm glad that the initializer list semantics is very specific about conversions--this might be a good reason for me to start using `{}` wherever I need code to be most portable so the compiler can catch conversion pitfalls before I actually target a new platform.